# why is set_intersection in STL so slow?

Tags: c#, c++, performance, stl, intersection

I'm intersecting a set of 100,000 numbers and a set of 1,000 numbers using set_intersection in STL and its taking 21s, where it takes 11ms in C#.

C++ Code:

```
int runIntersectionTestAlgo()
{   

    set<int> set1;
    set<int> set2;
    set<int> intersection;


    // Create 100,000 values for set1
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ )
    {
        int value = 1000000000 + i;
        set1.insert(value);
    }

    // Create 1,000 values for set2
    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
    {
        int random = rand() % 200000 + 1;
        random *= 10;

        int value = 1000000000 + random;
        set2.insert(value);
    }

    set_intersection(set1.begin(),set1.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end(), inserter(intersection, intersection.end()));

    return intersection.size(); 
}
```

C# Code:

```
static int runIntersectionTest()
    {
        Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        Dictionary<int,int> theMap = new Dictionary<int,int>();

        List<int> set1 = new List<int>();
        List<int> set2 = new List<int>();

            // Create 100,000 values for set1
            for ( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ )
            {
                int value = 1000000000 + i;
                set1.Add(value);
            }

            // Create 1,000 values for set2
            for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
            {
                int value = 1000000000 + (random.Next() % 200000 + 1);
                set2.Add(value);
            }

            // Now intersect the two sets by populating the map
        foreach( int value in set1 )
            {
                theMap[value] = 1;
            }

            int intersectionSize = 0;

        foreach ( int value in set2 )
        {
            int count;
            if ( theMap.TryGetValue(value, out count ) )
            {
                intersectionSize++;
                theMap[value] = 2;
            }
            }

            return intersectionSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a useful comment:
Are you timing the whole program, or just the set_intersection() call?

Comment: Are you timing both the creation of the initial sets as well as the intersection?

Comment: You do realize that the C++ std::set is a tree-based structure, while the C# Dictionary is an array-based hashtable, and List is just an array, right?  Before even considering the allocation problems of your code, you're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: In addition to the above problems. In the C# example you are not building the intersection of the sets (just getting the size). You need to make a third pass and remove all them members from 'theMap' that are only in set1.

Comment: how do you compile this? Looks like others have trouble reproducing your timings.

Comment: With C#, my tendency would be to use HashSets and "IntersectWith," rather than what you did.  But since C# isn't your problem, I'll leave this as a comment.

Comment: Pod - the whole program.  Dusty - all of it.  Not Sure - yes, I have experimented with variations in each of C++ and C#. Jalf - I left out some of the code (Need a way to ATTACH files to questions!)

Comment: No, just show the relevant code. We don't necessarily need more code than you've posted, but we would need to know 1) how it was compiled, and 2) exactly what you timed (just the intersection, or the entire program?)

Comment: The slow down was caused by running with the debugger attached. But, I appreciate your points and will give more detail in the future. 1 - compiled as Win32 Release, in VS2008 SP1.  2 - timed the whole program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this ancient 3GHz Pentium 4, I get 2734 milliseconds for the entire `runIntersectionTestAlgo` function, in a debug build with optimizations disabled. I compiled with VS2008 SP1.

If I enable optimizations, I get 93 milliseconds.

Here's my code:

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int runIntersectionTestAlgo()
{   

    set<int> set1;
    set<int> set2;
    set<int> intersection;


    // Create 100,000 values for set1
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ )
    {
        int value = 1000000000 + i;
        set1.insert(value);
    }

    // Create 1,000 values for set2
    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
    {
        int random = rand() % 200000 + 1;
        random *= 10;

        int value = 1000000000 + random;
        set2.insert(value);
    }

    set_intersection(set1.begin(),set1.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end(), inserter(intersection, intersection.end()));

    return intersection.size(); 
}

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    DWORD start = GetTickCount();

    runIntersectionTestAlgo();

    DWORD span = GetTickCount() - start;

    std::cout << span << " milliseconds\n";
}
```

Disabling `_SECURE_SCL` made no difference for the release build, which still hovered around the 100 ms.

`GetTickCount` isn't ideal, of course, but it should be good enough to distinguish 21 seconds from less than 100 milliseconds.

So I conclude that there's something wrong with your benchmarks.

Comment: Wow.  I took your code, ran it, and it ran in 31ms.  I then ran it with the debugger attached (as I'd been doing for my tests) and it ran in 23353 ms.

Comment: STL uses a lot of intermediate functions that need to be inlined for performance to be acceptable. GCC at least will let you enable debug and optimization simultaneously, and recent GDB versions can show and step through inlined function calls, so you can debug this stuff at bearable speed ;) You might try turning on inlining with no other optimizations and see what kind of speed you get.

Answer (score 8):

A couple things would make your two examples more comparable.

First, your example in STL isn't quite right, for one thing both sets should be sorted in ascending order (in STL speak a "strict weak ordering").

Second, your using "sets" which are implemented as trees in STL, vs. "lists" which are linked lists.  Random inserts into a set is more expensive than inserting onto the end of a list.

Try using a list of ints in the C++ example and also sort the list first (otherwise set inersection won't work properly) and I think you'll see more favorable results.

Answer (score 5):

I ran your C++ code on my linux box

```
$ time ./test

real    0m0.073s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.003s
```

21s means to me you compiled without optimizations. In case you use MSVC make sure you have listed
 `_SECURE_SCL=0` (see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985896(VS.80).aspx)) in the compile definitions.  Otherwise all STL iterator operations are dog slow.

Comment: +1 for _SCL_SECURE.  I hadn't heard of this flag before.  Do you know if it's disabled it for release builds?

Comment: This was topic of discussion at the boost mailing list.  They said _SCL_SECURE is enabled (set to 1) by default, even in Release mode.

Comment: It is enabled by default in debug and release builds. According to a presentation at this year's BoostCon, it will be disabled in release builds in VS2010. :)

Comment: whoops, it looks like it is _SECURE_SCL, not _SCL_SECURE :)

Comment: Hmmm, MSDN agrees with you, jalf.  Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I updated your example to use some timer code that I use when unit testing.  On my machine I get the following timings (based on -O3):

```
First loop 0.0040654
Second loop 4.8e-05
Intersection 0.000349
Intersection size: 50
```

Based on that, if I'm reading my decimals correctly, it takes '4ms' to insert the items into the first set, 50 microseconds to insert the items into the second set and a 1/3 of a ms to perform the intersection.

I am unable to run your C# example on my machine, so I cannot compare the timing, but it's definitely not 21s as you post.

Answer (score 0):

Your C# and C++ code work differently.  The C# code uses magical hashing tricks for speed, your C++ code uses tree tricks for speed.  One thing that will probably speed things up (ignoring the fact that your testing seems to be broken) would be to using hashing, as follows:

1. Create a `hash_map` of one of the two collections.
2. Iterate over each element in the 2nd collection.  If the `hash_map1 contains that element, add it to your result.

Comment: Yes they are different.  I previously tried the C# approach in C++ using each of std:map, stdext:hash_map and boost::unordered_set and got the same poor results.

I'm sure if I changed the C# code to use HashSet<int> and .IntersectWith it'd be as fast (or maybe faster).